# Amend MySQL Query to force a record to appear first?

Tags: mysql

I have the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM pages WHERE parent=0 ORDER BY `sort` ASC"
```

There is a bug somewhere in the system I am working with which means that a page can have a lower sort value than the home page. I am currently looking into this, in the meantime i need the query to enforce that home page comes out first.

Can this query be adapted so it always get's the page with an `id` of 1 to appear first, then rest are sorted by the sort column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    pages
ORDER BY
        id = 1 DESC, sort
```

If you are going to apply a `LIMIT` clause to this query, it may be better to split it in two:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    pages
WHERE   id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    pages
        WHERE   parent = 0
                AND id <> 1
        ORDER BY
                parent, sort
        LIMIT 9
        )
```

so that an index on `(parent, sort)` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE parent=0 ORDER BY IF( id = 1, -1, 0 ) ASC, id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE parent=0 ORDER BY `id` ASC, `sort` ASC
```

Comment: If `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY`, this would be the same as `ORDER BY id`.